# Create a custom List Calculated Coulmn using IF or Case structure

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a column in sharepoint 2010 foundation custom list which functions as the below code

If (Status = "Avail") then 
       -1
ElseIf ((Status = "Apply") then
       1
End IF

meaning that when ever while adding an item in the list the new column should have value 1 or -1 according to the option selected in column Status as Apply or Avail respectively.

Is it possible to create such a column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to do something like this:

```
=IF([Status]="Avail", "-1", "1")
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) is a great resource on calculated columns.

Comment: Great! Since it resolved your issue, you can click the little check mark to show that.